# Indentation before tables in landscape format

Tags: tables, margins, landscape

I'm using Latex for the first time and I'm using the template from  Sharelatex.com.

I have stripped it down as good as I could for this example.

I want the tables to spread over the whole text width (like the caption does) which normally was no problem within the normal document. Since I have a very large table, containing out of two subtables, I want it to be in landscape and there the trouble begins.

I don't know how to manipulate the space/indentation/margin between the start of table the page. Within the normal article it used to spread over the whole page when I was creating the tables like this. If I change the margin in the geometry package it moves the whole page content.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}%

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table} \centering 
{\captionsetup{justification=centering,singlelinecheck=off}
\caption{\bfseries\Large Title for table IV }\label{tab:renvarcov}}
\caption*{\small Referencing the return vector which is table \ref{tab:renvec} and referencing the variance co-variance matrix which is table \ref{tab:varcov}. demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description. Plus some more
text to test some other format}

    \begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
    \sisetup{table-format=-1.2}
    \centering
    \caption{Vector of expected returns}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{12}{S}@{}}
            \toprule
            Asset & $R_T$ & $U_T$ & $S_T$ & $P_{S B=F}$ & $C_{S B=F}$ & $P_{S B=38\;\$}$ & $C_{B=43.34\;\$}$ & $P_{U B=F}$  & $C_{U B=F}$ & $P_{R B=F}$ & $C_{R B=F}$ \\
            \midrule
            Return & 0.03 & 0.07 & 0.1 & -0.42 & 0.71 & -0.46 & 0.87 & -0.39 & 0.62 & -0.23 & 0.32 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:renvec}
    \end{subtable}

    \bigskip
    \begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}
    \sisetup{table-format=-1.3}
    \centering
    \caption{Variance-covariance-matrix}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{12}{S}@{}}
            \toprule
              & $R_T$ & $U_T$ & $S_T$ & $P_{S B = F}$ & $C_{S B = F}$  & $P_{S B = 38\;\$}$  & $P_{S B = 43.34\;\$}$  & $P_{U B = F}$  & $C_{U B = F}$ & $P_{R B = F}$ & $C_{R B = F}$ \\
            \midrule
            $R_T$ & 0.009 & -0.001 &    -0.002 &    0.008 & -0.018 &    0.008 & -0.023 &    0.004 & -0.009 &    -0.091 &    0.149  \\
            $U_T$ & -0.001 &    0.026 & 0.007 & -0.026 &    0.063 & -0.027 &    0.080 & -0.129 &    0.307 & 0.009 & -0.013  \\
            $S_T$ & -0.002 &    0.007 & 0.049 & -0.165 &    0.455 & -0.169 &    0.587 & -0.037 &    0.081 & 0.023 & -0.034  \\
            $P_{S B = F}$ & 0.008 & -0.026 &    -0.165 &    1.065 & -1.002 &    1.205 & -1.090 &    0.157 & -0.281 &    -0.081 &    0.133  \\
            $C_{S B = F}$ & -0.018 &    0.063 & 0.455 & -1.002 &    4.715 & -0.922 &    6.283 & -0.313 &    0.737 & 0.204 & -0.294 \\
            $P_{S B = 38\;\$}$ & 0.008 &    -0.027 &    -0.169 &    1.205 & -0.922 &    1.446 & -1.004 &    0.168 & -0.291 &    -0.084 &    0.142  \\
            $C_{S B = 43.34\;\$}$ & -0.023 &    0.080 & 0.587 & -1.090 &    6.283 & -1.004 &    8.598 & -0.388 &    0.944 & 0.261 & -0.369  \\
            $P_{U B = F}$ & 0.004 & -0.129 &    -0.037 &    0.157 & -0.313 &    0.168 & -0.388 &    1.168 & -0.993 &    -0.045 &    0.071  \\
            $C_{U B = F}$ & -0.009 &    0.307 & 0.081 & -0.281 &    0.737 & -0.291 &    0.944 & -0.993 &    4.134 & 0.098 & -0.145  \\
            $P_{R B = F}$ & -0.091 &    0.009 & 0.023 & -0.081 &    0.204 & -0.084 &    0.261 & -0.045 &    0.098 & 1.527 & -1.013 \\
            $C_{R B = F}$ & 0.149 & -0.013 &    -0.034 &    0.133 & -0.294 &    0.142 & -0.369 &    0.071 & -0.145 &    -1.013 &    3.146 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:varcov}
    \end{subtable}        
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Results in:
[image]

Any help what I could try to spread these tables over the whole page width?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Instead of `\begin{subtable}{1\textwidth}` use `\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one table in `landscape` orientation,, than is better to use `sideways` table from package `rotating` and instead of `\textwidth` (which is defined for portrait paper orientation) use `\linweidth`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,rotating}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}%

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering

\captionsetup{font={Large,bf}}% <-- changed
\caption{Title for table IV }
\label{tab:renvarcov}

\captionsetup{font=small, justification=justified}% <-- changed
\caption*{Referencing the return vector which is table \ref{tab:renvec} and referencing the variance co-variance matrix which is table \ref{tab:varcov}. demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description demo text for table description. Plus some more
text to test some other format}

    \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}% <-- changed
    \sisetup{table-format=-1.2}
    \centering
    \caption{Vector of expected returns}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{12}{S}@{}}
            \toprule
    Asset & $R_T$ & $U_T$ & $S_T$ & $P_{S B=F}$ & $C_{S B=F}$ & $P_{S B=38\;\$}$ & $C_{B=43.34\;\$}$ & $P_{U B=F}$  & $C_{U B=F}$ & $P_{R B=F}$ & $C_{R B=F}$ \\
    \midrule
    Return & 0.03 & 0.07 & 0.1 & -0.42 & 0.71 & -0.46 & 0.87 & -0.39 & 0.62 & -0.23 & 0.32 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:renvec}
    \end{subtable}

    \bigskip
    \begin{subtable}{\linewidth}% <-- changed
    \sisetup{table-format=-1.3}
    \centering
    \caption{Variance-covariance-matrix}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{12}{S}@{}}
    \toprule
      & $R_T$ & $U_T$ & $S_T$ & $P_{S B = F}$ & $C_{S B = F}$  & $P_{S B = 38\;\$}$  & $P_{S B = 43.34\;\$}$  & $P_{U B = F}$  & $C_{U B = F}$ & $P_{R B = F}$ & $C_{R B = F}$ \\
            \midrule
    $R_T$ & 0.009 & -0.001 &    -0.002 &    0.008 & -0.018 &    0.008 & -0.023 &    0.004 & -0.009 &    -0.091 &    0.149  \\
    $U_T$ & -0.001 &    0.026 & 0.007 & -0.026 &    0.063 & -0.027 &    0.080 & -0.129 &    0.307 & 0.009 & -0.013  \\
    $S_T$ & -0.002 &    0.007 & 0.049 & -0.165 &    0.455 & -0.169 &    0.587 & -0.037 &    0.081 & 0.023 & -0.034  \\
    $P_{S B = F}$ & 0.008 & -0.026 &    -0.165 &    1.065 & -1.002 &    1.205 & -1.090 &    0.157 & -0.281 &    -0.081 &    0.133  \\
    $C_{S B = F}$ & -0.018 &    0.063 & 0.455 & -1.002 &    4.715 & -0.922 &    6.283 & -0.313 &    0.737 & 0.204 & -0.294 \\
    $P_{S B = 38\;\$}$ & 0.008 &    -0.027 &    -0.169 &    1.205 & -0.922 &    1.446 & -1.004 &    0.168 & -0.291 &    -0.084 &    0.142  \\
    $C_{S B = 43.34\;\$}$ & -0.023 &    0.080 & 0.587 & -1.090 &    6.283 & -1.004 &    8.598 & -0.388 &    0.944 & 0.261 & -0.369  \\
    $P_{U B = F}$ & 0.004 & -0.129 &    -0.037 &    0.157 & -0.313 &    0.168 & -0.388 &    1.168 & -0.993 &    -0.045 &    0.071  \\
    $C_{U B = F}$ & -0.009 &    0.307 & 0.081 & -0.281 &    0.737 & -0.291 &    0.944 & -0.993 &    4.134 & 0.098 & -0.145  \\
    $P_{R B = F}$ & -0.091 &    0.009 & 0.023 & -0.081 &    0.204 & -0.084 &    0.261 & -0.045 &    0.098 & 1.527 & -1.013 \\
    $C_{R B = F}$ & 0.149 & -0.013 &    -0.034 &    0.133 & -0.294 &    0.142 & -0.369 &    0.071 & -0.145 &    -1.013 &    3.146 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:varcov}
    \end{subtable}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]